# Hugging Face Models Installation Firewalled Environment or Using Conda

Tags: python, conda, huggingface-transformers, machine-translation

We would like to run hugging face transformer models in a firewalled environment. So, when installed transformers using conda (pointing to org jfrog repo) and tried running, it tries to download model files to cache folder in runtime which is failed.

However, my org will not allow downloading files via internet and place them manually in cache to run them offline. Only allowed way is via Conda install, does anyone aware if these hugging face transformer models are available in conda repo? can help provide conda package name of this?
Any pointers will be helpful.

Please note we already referred to this https://huggingface.co/transformers/installation.html, but not useful in this context because we are forbidden to download files via internet.

Comment: Have you seen [this section](https://huggingface.co/transformers/installation.html#with-conda)?

Comment: I did saw this. Process in my org is very stringent to download packages that were not part of Conda package, thus looking for a solution if these are available as conda packages

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by a conda packae? In my understanding, doing `conda install -c huggingface transformers` would install the `conda` package `transformers`, so wouldn't it fit your description?